# ¿Cómo inserto y guardo imágenes en un crud en Visual 2022?

Tags: c#, crud, cshtml

[image: Formulario de la vista Create]
i[image: CRUD]

Hola, quiero que en un crud se puedan subir imágenes así como se ve y que se guarden con cada registro pero solo me ha funcionado el "Input" que se ve en código más abajo, me muestra el botón de subir archivo pero no se guarda.

Ese es el Create de la tabla en la que quiero que se guarden las imágenes:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Imagen" class="control-label"></label>
            <input type="file" name="imageload"/>
         <span asp-validation-for="Imagen" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hola Camilo. Necesitaremos más información. Qué significa *cómo hacer que la imagen se guarde con el registro de usuario.*? Tienes problema con subir la imagen al controlador MVC? Tienes problemas guardando la imagen con Entity Framework, o con el procedimiento almacenado? Tienes un error de lado de la base de datos? Tu API no acepta imágenes? Por favor edita tu pregunta y añade los detalles que creas relevantes

Comment: Ya edité la publicación, soy nuevo en esto disculpen si hago mal las preguntas.

Comment: Visual Studio es un IDE, supongo que a lo que te refieres es a como hacerlo en ASP.NET Core? Admás no m,encionas en que motor de bases de datos ni que librería de acceso a datos estás utilizando